# Normal video not playing in Firefox (youtube video is playing fine)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, youtube, http-headers

This is a sample of request headers of a youtube video in Firefox -

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection: keep-alive
Host: r6---sn-gvbxgn-tt1e.googlevideo.com
Origin: https://www.youtube.com
Referer: https://www.youtube.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0
```

The interesting thing is that there is no `Range: a-b` header in the request, which usually exists in a similar request made by Chrome.

Also, I noticed that youtube sends `.webm` video file in Firefox and `.mp4` video file in Chrome.

Now, when I try to play my `.mp4` video in Firefox, Firefox just sends a single request to the server with `Range: 0-` header. While my server expects continuous requests with changing Range  values in header, like in Chrome!

So my question is -  
How does Firefox send multiple video requests to youtube? Does it have to do something with `.webm` vs `.mp4` files?

Answer (score 0):

Range: 0- is completely legal. It means “start at byte zero and send the rest of the file”. Firefox expects servers to be standard compliment. If your server is not, make sure it does not set The accept-range header.

Comment: I get that it is legal, but why does Firefox send only a single request? Sending a 100MB video file, if a user meant to see only the first 5 sec, and then stop the video, would be a waste of my server's bandwidth! (I think you intended to say standard compliant, and not standard compliment in your answer)

Comment: You can’t control how much the browser will download (without using MSE). So as to “why” Mozilla does what it does, only Mozilla can answer that. But note the browser may choose to abort the download (safari does this frequently), or slow the stream by accepting fewer packets after a minimum buffer is reached.